# R - Coerce list into dataframe, keeping column-variables together

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

I have a list of named vectors:

```
> x <- list(c(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4),c(a=5, b=6 ,c=7 ,d=8),c(a=32, c=46, d=55, e=100))
> x
[[1]]
a b c d 
1 2 3 4 

[[2]]
a b c d 
5 6 7 8 

[[3]]
  a   c   d   e 
 32  46  55 100
```

I would like to coerce this into a data.frame such that values named similarly fall into one column:

```
> y <- data.frame(a=c(1,5,32), b=c(2,6,NA), c=c(3,7,46), d=c(4,8,55), e=c(NA,NA,100))
> y
   a  b  c  d   e
1  1  2  3  4  NA
2  5  6  7  8  NA
3 32 NA 46 55 100
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with the **dplyr** package:

```
require(dplyr)

data.frame(bind_rows(!!! x))

#or for a tibble, use: bind_rows(!!! x)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d   e
1  1  2  3  4  NA
2  5  6  7  8  NA
3 32 NA 46 55 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `purrr::map_df` and `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_df(x,bind_rows)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
      a     b     c     d     e
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3     4    NA
2     5     6     7     8    NA
3    32    NA    46    55   100
```

Comment: I cannot call the map_df function under dplyr::　　

> library(dplyr)
> map_df(x,bind_rows)
錯誤: 沒有這個函數 "map_df"

Comment: Sorry - it is in `purrr` not `dplyr`!  Amended above.

Comment: Now it's this error:　　　
> map_df(x,bind_rows)
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : cannot find object 'bind_rows'

Comment: Sorry - it is `bind_rows` that is in `dplyr`.

Comment: What does <dbl> stand for over here? Comparing with @Ryan's solution, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: @Ryan, I agree. : ) But aren't tibbles supposed to function similarly, or even  better than a dataframe? It is said on the manual page that: 'Tibbles are a modern take on data frames. They keep the features that have stood the test of time, and drop the features that used to be convenient but are now frustrating. '

Comment: @Sati The `<dbl>` is just indicating the data type (double precision number) of each column. It is not part of the data frame. This is one of the things that happens when you print a df that is also a `tibble`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(x, as.data.frame.list), fill = TRUE)
#    a  b  c  d   e
#1:  1  2  3  4  NA
#2:  5  6  7  8  NA
#3: 32 NA 46 55 100
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
un1 <- unique(unlist(lapply(x, names)))
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(y) {
   y[setdiff(un1, names(y))] <- NA
   y[un1]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(i) 
                            data.frame(a=i['a'], b=i['b'], c=i['c'], 
                                       d=i['d'], e=i['e'])))
row.names(df) <- NULL

df
#    a  b  c  d   e
# 1  1  2  3  4  NA
# 2  5  6  7  8  NA
# 3 32 NA 46 55 100
```